# /will/ or /wəl/ in this audio?

Tags: pronunciation

*We **will** start the day with cloudy skies.*

([here](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/482) is the audio of the above sentence )

Is the *will* **in this audio file** pronounced as [/will/ or /wəl/](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/will)?

To me, I hear that the speaker's vowel for *will* is not as near as /[ə](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-central_vowel)/ or as /[i](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_unrounded_vowel)/.

How does he pronounce the word?

Comment: Strictly speaking it probably *is* a neutral schwa. But that's not easy for native speakers to be aware of, since we "hear" what we *expect* in such contexts. I can't imagine that it would make sense for a non-native speaker to seek to *emulate* such diction though. Usually the speaker himself is unaware of what he's doing, but I can easily imagine it seeming "odd" if it's done indiscriminately. Best stick to enunciating all vowels except those where nearly everyone uses a schwa *and knows they do*.

Comment: I hear it there as a shortened "wool", deeper than schwa. This is a regional variation. In parts of the south with twangy accents, you'll hear a dipthong, "weal". Up north, it's a high front vowel that rhymes with "pill".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"will" is a common "add-on" or auxillary word.  That's why it's often contracted = "we'll, they'll, I'll, etc."  Thus there is a tendency to run the two words together, and let the vowel in "will" fall to a schwa as though "we will" was one word with accent on the "we."

You'll never be misunderstood if you clearly pronounce the short i in will in all instances, though.

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily answered with a dictionary.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will

even has a 'listen' button

Comment: I think the OP is asking about a specific instance of pronunciation.